Wisdom and knowledge, G-dly or unG-dly?
I wondered if there are texts and/or explanations that teach us when certain knowledge or wisdom is considered G-dly or unG-dly (occult, pagan, wrong).
To give some context, I recently had a discussion with someone who believed that certain Yoga exercises and withdrawal exercises were occult because they originated in other cultures, beliefs and philosophy. Likewise, people should not learn anything from philosophy, Buddhist wisdom and other teachings.
In my view, the things, certain words or actions themselves are often not occult, pagan or unG-dly, but this is determined by context, the definition one gives to certain words, and the intention or background from which one does things determine whether something is right or wrong.
For example, if I use foreign knowledge, quote a non-Jewish teacher to proclaim or clarify my Jewish message, when I use certain examples to ultimately explain, proclaim and convey a divine message, am I in the wrong?

The Gemara (Niddah 30b) has both, the Hachamim and Ribbi Yishmael, quoting "scientists" to prove their point and bashing the other one's proof "a proof from the fools". Seemingly they had no problem with science being used to back up their point, but at the same time, had no problem saying science is worthless when it is against the Torah.
The Rabbis also did not allow learning any form of foreign (Greek) wisdom (Sotah 9:14, Sanhedrin 10:1), but clearly knew it themselves. They warned not to hang out with people who deny God, nor go to their schools (Avot d'Ribbi Natan 2:7). The Rambam and the Ramban (forgot source) say something along the lines of facts are facts when it comes to science (see Eichah Rabbah 2:13).
There is no clear line given for yes or no if it is not clearly pagan. The overall rule seems to be "Go and search for an hour that is neither part of the day nor part of the night, and learn Greek wisdom in it" (M'nachot 99b), i.e. don't go looking learning other wisdoms (since Torah is all inclusive Avot 5:22), but if you need it to understand Torah or for a job, it's fine.

The Midrash says:

If someone tells you that there is wisdom among the nations, believe him. [If someone tells you] that there is Torah among the nations, do not believe him. [Lamentations Rabbah 2:13]

Since we must pursue wisdom, we must therefore take it wherever we find it.

Rabbi Reuven Agushevitz wrote 3 short books on philosohy, which might help draw the line: "Principles of Philosophy", "Ancient Greek Philosophy", and "Faith And Heresy".
